# Having trouble adding values to associative array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an issue with adding value at the first position in an associative array, i've tried googling on the internet, used several methods to add a value but still it's not adding the value at the first position.

what i tried is

```
array_unshift($output_countries['CountryName'], "India");
```

but it doesn't work

my PHP code:

```
while($rows_fetch_country_list = mysql_fetch_array($query_country_list)) {
    extract($rows_fetch_country_list);


      $output_countries[] = array(
           "CountryName" => $country_name,
           "CountryCode" => $country_code,
           "Id" => $pk_country_id
      );


}
```

any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do in more detail? Your "what I tried" code doesn't really make sense. Are you trying to add a country array to your list of countries? Where is the rest of the data for India?

Comment: rest of the data is coming from db, after the results are stored i want to add a static value to the list of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can prepend a value to an existing array. You're correct to use unshift, but you probably want your static value to look like your DB records, and the first parameter for unshift should just be the target array.

```
<?php
//Your static record
$staticCountry = ['CountryName' => 'India',  'CountryCode' => 'IN', 'Id' => 0];

//Results from DB
$countries = [
    ['CountryName' => 'Canada',  'CountryCode' => 'CA', 'Id' => 1],
    ['CountryName' => 'France',  'CountryCode' => 'FR', 'Id' => 2],
    ['CountryName' => 'Germany',  'CountryCode' => 'DE', 'Id' => 3]
];    

array_unshift($countries, $staticCountry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this technique:

```
    $country[0] = array("Nepal" => "Nepal", "CountryCode" => 'NP',"Id" => 01);
    $country[1] = array("India" => "India", "CountryCode" => 'IN',"Id" => 02);
    $firstItem[0] = array('Pakistan' => 'Pakistan',"CountryCode" => 'PK',"Id" => 03);

    $arr= array_merge($firstItem, $country);
    print_r($arr);
```